# How to render twig variable as HTML attribute name

Tags: html, twig, twig-extension, twig.js

I am trying to set a custom HTML attribute name using twig, trying to achieve this:

```
<div age="24"> Something </div>
```

This is my code:

```
{% set custom_age_attribute= "age" %}
<div {{custom_age_attribute}}="24"> Something </div>
```

But the twig code is not rendering and getting this:

```
<div {{custom_age_attribute}}="24"> Something </div>
```

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Can't [reproduce](https://twigfiddle.com/0dpjyf) - Did you by change edited the lexer?

Comment: Not sure. Although the code inside double quotes is rendering fine
ex: 
`{% set custom_age_attribute= "age" %}
<div "{{custom_age_attribute}}"="24"> Something </div>`